# ZF | New on ZF | Autoloader why seem to not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

The downloaded version is the ZF 2.1

I have enter the following code in my basic file of my appliction, and it seems to be not corect:

```
$path   =   dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Zend';
ini_set(
    'include_path',
    ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path
);

require_once('/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php');
$loader = new \Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(
    array(
        'Zend' => $path,
    )
);
$loader->register();

$m = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
```

The error I am getting is the following:

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mail\Message' not found in **PathToMyFile**

Any idea on what is it wrong with that ?

Is there any good tutorial to start with Autoloading in Zend Framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want:

```
$path   =   dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library'
```

in your include path.

However, I would guess that this is in your index.php, which is in your public directory, and what you really want is to go up one dir from there, then into the library dir:

```
$path   =   dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'library'
```

Comment: That was the issue !! Thanks :)